# opencv java ip-camera (2 questions)

Tags: java, opencv, ip-camera

this is first time i'm working with ip camera (D-LINK DCS-5605), my final task is to detect objects and FOLLOW THEM (control ip camera)...

I've already wrote java code that detects objects in a way i want usint openCV...

Now i need to work with ip camera from java using opencv.

Question 1) How to detect ip camera via OpenCV?

Question 2) How to control it via java?

Anything will be useful to me,
Your help will be appreciated :)
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Dear friends, as i see no responses here,
so there is what i found with my research...

There is a way to do this if you use C, there is special method for that, but unfortunately in java interface it is not accessible...

So i think if i really decide to achieve this with java, then i'll need to modify OpenCV.java and export new modified jar...

hope this will be useful for someone...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you aren't monitoring this question anymore but in case you are or anyone else stumbles upon it you can use JNI (Java Native Interface) to connect OpenCV (The C/C++ version) and Java together. This will allow you to either connect to your camera via Java and pass the images back to OpenCV or connect via OpenCV and pass them forward to Java, depending on your preference.

I'm still working on finding the best way to connect to an IP camera via Java but the Xuggler library works pretty well and has a small learning curve. But to connect via OpenCV you may be able to just put in the address of the camera source to the CreateFileCapture method, along the lines of:

```
 CvCapture *camera = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://username:password@your.IP.address.here:554/ch1-s1");
```

Which works for me. The actual string you pass will depend on the camera.

As for controlling the camera via Java, assuming you are talking about a PTZ camera then sending the commands via http should work.